# does "in the island of Jamaica" refer to "her life had been.."?

Tags: meaning

does "in the island of Jamaica" refer to "her life had been.." in the following context?

Her earth name had been Morgan, and King was rather the
general title of a certain class of spirits than an ordinary name. Her life
had been spent two hundred years before, in the reign of Charles the
Second, in the island of **Jamaica**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It means she spent her life in Jamaica.

I should point out that "in *the island of* Jamaica" is a little unusual - although we say "in" a country, we normally say "on" an island.

"During" the reign of Charles the Second would also be slightly better.

Comment: 'In' an island is old fashioned nowadays, but was at one time very common.